# Error: preferences.xml:com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android-layout

I'm getting the following error when I try to display the graphical layout view in Eclipse,

Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- PreferenceCategory (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- PreferenceScreen (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

I have seen this asked before but was not answered. Should I be concerned that it's a problem ? Lint does not seem to find anything wrong with it.

Thanks in advance